# Invalid Argument Error when using Tensorboard callback

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorboard

I have used a Tensorboard callback in fitting a model consisting of one embedding layer and one SimpleRNN layer. The model performs binary sentiment classification for 9600 input text sequences. They have been tokenised and padded in advance.

```
# 1. Remove previous logs
!rm -rf ./logs/
# 2. Change to Py_file_dir
os.chdir(...)

# input_dim = 43489 (size of tokenizer word dictionary); output_dim = 100 (GloVe 100d embeddings); input_length = 1403 (length of longest text sequence).
# xtr_pad is padded, tokenised text sequences. nrow = 9600, ncol = input_length = 1403. 

model= Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length= input_length, 
                       weights= [Embedding_matrix], trainable= False))
model.add(SimpleRNN(200))
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
tb = TensorBoard(histogram_freq=1, log_dir= 'tbcallback_prac')
tr_results= model.fit(xtr_pad, ytr, epochs= 2, batch_size= 64, verbose= 1, 
                      validation_split= 0.2, callbacks= [tb])

# In command prompt enter: tensorboard --logdir tbcallback_prac
```

- I have run this on Jupyterlab and on the first time the model trains without issue. I was able to view the Tensorboard statistics on local host.

  However when I run this same code a second time, i.e. removing logs and fitting model it completed the first epoch of training, but returns this error before the 2nd epoch begins.

```
Train on 7680 samples, validate on 1920 samples

Epoch 1/2
7680/7680 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2919 - accuracy: 0.9004
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a1cde9b5b1f4> in <module>()
      7 tb = TensorBoard(histogram_freq=1, log_dir= 'tbcallback_prac')
      8 tr_results= model.fit(xtr_pad, ytr, epochs= 2, batch_size= 64, verbose= 1, 
----> 9                       validation_split= 0.2, callbacks= [tb])

...
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'embedding_input' with dtype float and shape [?,1403]
     [[{{node embedding_input}}]]
```

Note 1403 is the length of all padded, tokenised sequences in training input 'xtr'.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: My model was able to be fitting repeatedly using a custom callback. The error only arises when using the Tensorboard callback

Comment: I read it, someone told in a post that is because it is for custom display but with the custom callback you can reduce its loggings sizes.